# getting notifiable and implementing custom morph relation in Laravel notification

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-8

I want to get the `notifiable model` relation while getting notifications for a specific user. And plus I want to save and get custom morph relation (i.e. `causer` (`causer_id` and `causer_type`)) in notification table (just like `notifiable`). I was able to create a morph relation and saving it into table record but I am having trouble while getting the relation model, it returns `null` in both relations. Sharing the code.

- custom `DatabaseChannel` -- the modified buildPayload method.

```
protected function buildPayload($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        $data = $this->getData($notifiable, $notification);
        $causer = $data['causer'];

        unset($data['causer']);

        return [
            // README: removed uuid from here
            'type' => method_exists($notification, 'databaseType')
                ? $notification->databaseType($notifiable)
                : get_class($notification),
            'data' => $data,
            'read_at' => null,
            'causer_type' => get_class($causer),
            'causer_id' => $causer->id,
        ];
    }
```

- custom `notifiable` trait

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable as BaseNotifiable;

trait Notifiable
{
    use BaseNotifiable;

    /**
     * Get the entity's notifications.
     */
    public function notifications(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Notification::class, 'notifiable')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

and one thing more I'd like to ask here, how can I refer to two morph relations to single table, like I want to add `notifications` method with `causer` and as well as `notifiable`.

- custom `Notifications` Model

```
class Notification extends DatabaseNotification
{
    public function causer()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

what I am missing or doing wrong? Is it even possible what I am trying to do?

Comment: have you got the solution? I'm looking for the same thing

Comment: Please  see the answer below

Comment: I want to add records first. How did you add causer_type and causer_id in notification table? If you can provide some details Please

Comment: just create a migration and update `notifications` table.

Comment: It seems I was not able to explain my issue correctly here, I added custom notifiable to notifications table but I'm not able to store it.

Comment: can you share your code? create another question and paste its link here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242807/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-abdullah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get morph relation (one or maybe two), you need to select columns `{morph}_id` and `{morph}_type`, this is just in case if you are using `->select()` while getting records, if you are not using `select`, that'd not be doing any issue.

**EDIT**

Here is how you add custom columns to `notifications` table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string("causer_type")->after('notifiable_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger("causer_id")->after('causer_type');
            $table->index(["causer_type", "causer_id"]);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropMorphs('causer');
        });
    }
```